# BGE. How do I make the plane stop the ball

Tags: game-engine

I am a first-time user of the BGE and I am trying to follow a tutorial on the BGE with a ball and a plane, but after following the instructions so far, the ball goes straight through the plane. How do I make the plane stop the ball from falling?

Answer (score 2):

First, set the ball to dynamic or rigid in the properties toolbar under the physics tab. Then set the plane's physics tab to static if you want it to remain still.

If the ball still goes through. In the same physics bar tick "collision bounds" and put respective collision bounds to each item. I guess box to the plane and sphere to the ball.

Comment: That's what I did and the ball still goes through the plane.

Comment: Share your blend file through here and post the link after : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I tried it in another version of Blender and it worked. Thanks anyway.